# HP Pavilion dv6 overheating, how do I set fan speed to 100% all the time?

Tags: windows-7, fan, temperature, overheating

So I have a HP Pavilion dv6, and it works fine. But when I play, say, Minecraft, the temperature jumps to around 60c-70c. I wouldn't be bothered by this, but I bought this computer and played Minecraft on my lap. The laptop overheated and the video card melted. (I'm not kidding) So I was wondering how I could set the fan speed on my laptop to 100% all the time so it never overheats. HP has this "HP Coolsense" thing that when I pick up the laptop and wiggle it around a little bit and pretend it's unstable, the fan cranks up to 100%. I want 100% all the time without me having to pick up the laptop every 10 minutes.
Thanks,
henpenben

Answer (score 1):

How about get a laptop cooling pad? I have a DV6 from earlier this year, and I'm almost completely sure Minecraft is capable of making its fan go full blast. Sure sounds like it, alright! I could tell you the result of me trying a cooling pad on my laptop before you buy one, if you like.

Now, how about you play Minecraft on a table or desk or something like that? After all, you'd probably need to do that in order to use a cooling pad. You should try it before you get a cooling pad. Strange thing is, I don't think my DV6 could ever get hot enough to burn me. I guess yours is certainly different than mine.

---

Well, in that case, I suppose you're left with updating the BIOS, and if that doesn't fix it, or you already have the latest BIOS, then you might just have to hack the BIOS. I have not done this before and I cannot guarantee that your computer will stay working by doing so.

Strangely enough, I've seen a similar issue of flickering horizontal lines near the top of the screen at times on my own dv6, and I don't think it's related to overheating. Rebooting seems to fix it. I recall it happening sometime during the first OS session on my laptop.

---

It seems Minecraft doesn't make my fan go full speed after all. Not having any system troubles, though. CPU is ~70 C.

Comment: I do use tables if I ever play any games, but when it melted I was sitting on my bed with a down comforter between my laptop and my lap. I learned that lesson the hard way. I have been looking at cooling pads, but I really want one that is powered by USB and I can use on my lap. I don't like being stuck at tables when I play games because the only desk in my house has a plastic chair. Also, like I said, I know Minecraft doesn't crank up the fan all the way because when I pick it up and make it think it's unstable, the fan gets louder. I tried Speedfan already and that didn't work...

Comment: I also changed all of the BIOS settings and AMD control center settings, _and_ the control panel settings so the fan runs at maximum capacity and the processors and drivers and other such things are able to run at 100% whenever they feel like it. I want to get the maximum speed out of my computer without completely killing it, and I know when it is overheating because I get flickering vertical lines on the screen when it starts to overheat. Cooling pads are nice, but laptops should have good enough fans that I don't have to place it on the left side of the desk so it blows onto air.

Comment: @henpenben It's a problem with the model in general.  I don't play any games, the computer wasn't on "high performance", and we still managed to melt our video card into oblivion.  See if giving it a thorough cleaning will clear the fans a bit, and if it's not prohibitive, look into a new system.

Comment: I just realized another thing you could try. Go grab the new HP Support Assistant from HP, it should give you a new version of CoolSense. Run that new version of CoolSense, and you should be able to configure it to have the fan go faster no matter if the laptop is stationary or not!

Answer (score 1):

@henpenben:

Don't be foolish. Buy a new chair and use your laptop on the table.  Seriously.  A chair is cheaper than a new computer and using it on your lap, especially if you're gonna play games, on a laptop that already has serious heat issues from the factory, WILL DESTROY YOUR COMPUTER. This is not a a matter of if it is a matter of when.

I just redid the cooling paste in one at the shop here and that dropped it about 15 degrees but it still idles around 65-75 which is ridiculous.